# Pan and zoom on an "infinite" graph paper background in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

For a project I'm working on I would like to have a background that I can pan around indefinitely, zoom in and out of and position and move around elements on that background.

The closest example I can think of is this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator. Additionally I will position different elements on top of that grid and move them around. For that I plan to use React and that isn't going to be much of a problem. The main issue I have is how to build the said background so that it can check all my requirements. I'm able to draw a grid but for moving around and zooming in and out (such that all the elements "on top" of the grid also scale up and down) is proving challenging for me. I would also like it if it can be done without the use of any specific drawing libraries and just pure JS but i'm open to suggestions. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I'm looking for general guidelines to how I can achieve my goal. For example different technologies or methods and not concrete solutions. I apologise if the question is too vague or badly formatted as it's the first time I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Desmos uses canvas to draw the "infinite" grid. You can achieve this using something like three.js or konva.js. One drawback of canvas is that you cannot place HTML elements on the grid.

Edit: Using three JS, you can use the gridHelper function and set the rotation about the x-axis by Pi. This should give you a "2d" grid. However, I found gsap and the Draggable plugin were better suited for this.

https://codepen.io/osiv/pen/gOwxmvO

This is definitely a work-in-progress, but it gives the idea of what I am working for. Zooming is basically preventing the default wheel behavior and changing the background image size:

```
handleWheelEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let el = document.getElementById("grid-container");
    let currengBackgroundSize = this.getPixelStringAsInteger(getComputedStyle(el).backgroundSize);
    if(e.deltaY < 0) {
        // decrease size
    } else {
        // increase size
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this too! Could you point me to a place in the three.js docs that address this? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Matt. Yes the drawback of canvas not allowing HTML elements on the grid is what prevents me from using it. My current setup consists of using linear-gradients as a background image, but the problem of scaling and panning still remains.

Comment: @markes try this - codepen.io/osiv/pen/dypzvvQ 

You can use gsap + Draggable to aid with the panning. You should be able to make the width / height of a container dynamic by using the onDrag callback and listening for the boundingClientRect left/right, top/bottom to be within a threshold of your edge. Scaling is a bit more difficult with the html approach over canvas. I was able to get this working by preventing the default wheel event and then modifying the "background-size" of the grid. However, you will need to scale all children's x,y coordinates and size accordingly.